# Unable to link two scripts together in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created two scripts in a unity game I am developing. The first is a script called Changetext (See below) and this seems to work fine, however, I would like it to only run when a player enters a set area in the game world so I created a second script called TRigger (See below)  which I tried to use to create a way in which whenever the player enters a trigger collider it calls this script making but whenever I try this unity just errors saying "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Changetext : MonoBehaviour {
public float timeLeft = 5;
public Text countdownText;
void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
     countdownText.text = ("Time Left = " + timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        countdownText.text = "You got the cash";
    }
}

}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class TRigger : MonoBehaviour
 { 
 void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Changetext>().enabled = false;
}
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    GetComponent<Changetext>().enabled = true;
}

void OnTriggerLeave()
{
    GetComponent<Changetext>().enabled = false;
}


}
```

Comment: Are both of these scripts on the same GameObject?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you don't have to include `UnityEngine.UI` in your second script.

It seems like your scripts are not attached to the same gameobject, which is essential for `GetComponent` in this case.

If your scripts shouldn't be on the same gameobject, you can just make a reference to your changetext, like

```
 private GameObject changetext;

void Start()
{
  changetext = FindObjectOfType<Changetext>().gameObject;
}
```

And then call it with

```
changetext.GetComponent<Changetext>().enabled = true;
```

Note: this only works if you only have one `Changetext` in your scene.
The version without declaring a gameobject should be the following:

```
 private Changetext changetext;

void Start()
{
  changetext = FindObjectOfType<Changetext>().gameObject.GetComponent<Changetext>();
}
```

And then call it with

```
changetext.enabled = true;
```

Comment: thank you but I need them to be on separate objects because one needs to affect the text and one needs to be attached to the player as they will be the one entering the collider

Comment: I just updated my answer for that purpose.

Comment: This is a bad implementation, in both performance and code structure. `FindObjectOfType` only works well if you have only one object that contains the script which may not be the case. Consider rathing using a `public Changetext changetext;`, in order to be able to assign it in the inspector. Additionally, if you want to use `FindObjectOfType`, just store the variable immediatly as a `Changetext`, don't bother calling `GetComponent`.

Comment: @Alexander I tried using your code you suggested but it gives me an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Changetext' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: @SamCrerar try `changetext = FindObjectOfType<Changetext>().gameObject;` instead, but like Ian already stated, my version might not be the best solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

As Alexander M. said in his answer, your code only works if both scripts are attached to the same object.

His answer suggests one method of acquiring that reference, but it is performance intensive and only works if there's exactly 1 copy of that script in the entire scene (two copies will have deterministic, but possibly undesired, behavior).

You probably want something like this:

```
public class TRigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        other.GetComponent<Changetext>().enabled = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        other.GetComponent<Changetext>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Note the added parameter to `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` (renamed from `OnTriggerLeave`): These are neccessary otherwise you have functions which will never be called because they are not in the [MonoBehaviour script reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

The above code will find the `Changetext` *on the object that touched the trigger volume.* If this is not where the script is located, you will need other methods to get a reference, such as manually assigning it to a field or using [`GameObject.Find()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html), which should only be done in `Start()` or `Awake()` or similar and the result cached in a class property.

Comment: There's another possibility: he didn't feed a `Text` type reference to the `countdownText` field, which could cause the NullReference exception.

Comment: @Galandil That is also true. Though comments have indicated that the asker *`need[s the two scripts] to be on separate objects`*, so that was indeed a problem that GetComponent the way he was using it was failing in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you need these scripts to be on separate objects, you should also do proper separation of concerns here. Key aspects:

Your Text object should have a ChangeTextScript on it. Its only concern is to start updating text when told so from another script. That's why it needs a public method called **StartChangingText** that can be called from outside and possibly a **ResetText** method to be called once player exits the trigger area in case you wish to display a "Player left the trigger area" message or something similar.

Your player object should have a TriggerScript on it. Once player enters the trigger area, this script should just call **StartChangingText** mentioned above. When player leaves the trigger area, it could call **ResetText**.

To implement this, first rename your Text object in the hierarchy to "CountdownText" in order for TriggerScript on the player object to find it by name, which is a safer method of referencing objects than drag and dropping objects to inspector fields. Then add a new component to the player object and name it ChangeTextScript. Paste this updated version of your code into it:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeTextScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float timeLeft = 5f;
    private Text countdownText; //you can also set Text to public and
                                // drag the Text object into the inspector field,
                                // but it's prone to initialization errors when 
                                // switching scenes or not saving your project

    bool shouldBeChangingText = false;

    void Start() {
        countdownText = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void StartChangingText() {
        shouldBeChangingText = true;
    }

    public void ResetText() {
        shouldBeChangingText = false;
        countdownText.text = "Player left the area";
        timeLeft = 5f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (shouldBeChangingText) {
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
            countdownText.text = ("Time Left = " + timeLeft);

            if (timeLeft <= 0)
            {
                shouldBeChangingText = false;
                countdownText.text = "You got the cash";
                timeLeft = 5f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add a new component to the player object, name it TriggerScript and paste this updated code into it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private ChangeTextScript changeTextScript;

    void Start() {
        changeTextScript = GameObject.Find("CountdownText").GetComponent<ChangeTextScript>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    { 
        changeTextScript.StartChangingText();
    }

    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        changeTextScript.ResetText();
    }
}
```

Note, when the timer runs out, we tell our script it should stop updating text, but we reset the timer so it can be started again, no need to enable and disable the script when you wish to run it again.

Also, in your original script, setting **gameObject.enabled** to true/false is deprecated in favor of **gameObject.SetActive(bool value)**.